# VLOOKUP returns #N/A in PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: php, wordpress, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to work with a calculator implemented in excel file with phpspreadsheet. Working with multiple sheets. First sheet has calculator itself.

Am I putting values right in way in it?

```
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load('calc.xlsx');
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D8', 210000);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D9', 160000);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D10', '5%');
$worksheet->setCellValue('D11', 30);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D12', -1073);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D15', 50000);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D16', '7%');
$worksheet->setCellValue('D19', 5000);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D20', 5000);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D21', 4500);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D24', '12/7/2018');
```

Because below code outputs #N/A

```
$worksheet->setCellValue('I8', '=VLOOKUP("L",Daily!A:N,3,FALSE)');
echo $worksheet->getCell('I8')->getFormattedValue();
```

Trying to do this in a wrdpress plugin.

Answer (score 1):

My Excel was very complex and I faced this same issue.
After hours of google-search and R&D I solved it by passing the sheet-name along with the cell.

The formula which caused me issue is:
**=VLOOKUP(B3,'Resort'!D5:L185,9)**

The V-Lookup formula which solved the issue is:
**=VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!B3,'Resort'!D5:L185,9)**

Answer (score 0):

What is on the sheet named "Daily" in your VLOOKUP formula? I used the same code and the following was produced on Sheet 1:

[image: Sheet1]

I also included what I had on the "Daily" sheet for testing purposes.

[image: Daily]

```
$path = 'c:/xxx/xxx/desktop/TestDoc.xlsx';

$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($path);
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D8', 210000);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D9', 160000);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D10', '5%');
$worksheet->setCellValue('D11', 30);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D12', -1073);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D15', 50000);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D16', '7%');
$worksheet->setCellValue('D19', 5000);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D20', 5000);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D21', 4500);
$worksheet->setCellValue('D24', '12/7/2018');
$worksheet->setCellValue('I8', '=VLOOKUP("L",Daily!A:N,3,FALSE)');
echo $worksheet->getCell('I8')->getFormattedValue();
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx");
$writer->save('c:/xxx/xxx/desktop/TestDoc.xlsx');
```